# Zend Framework: Incomplete object error when passing a value from controller to view

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, serialization, controller

I'm passing a user object from the controller to the view, then calling a method on that controller.  I've done a print_r on the object in the view, so I know it's the right object with the right values.  The current_user variable is an instance of the user class.

Here is the line in the layout that gives the error.

```
<?php echo $this->current_user->get_avatar_url(); ?>
```

Here is the method in the user class it's calling

```
public function get_avatar_url()
{
    return !empty($this->avatar) ? $this->avatar : $this->fb_userid != '' ? "http://graph.facebook.com/".$this->fb_userid."/picture" : "/public/images/pukie.jpg";
}
```

This is the error I get

> **Fatal error**:  main() The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "User" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in **/home/breathel/public_html/application/views/layouts/layout.phtml** on line **48**

I'm including the full controller base where this in called in case it makes a difference

```
<?php
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Action');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('User');

class BaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $current_user;
    protected $db;

    protected function initialize_values()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if($auth->hasIdentity())
        {
            $this->current_user = $auth->getIdentity();
            $this->view->current_user = $this->current_user;
        }

        $this->db = Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter');

        $this->view->controller_name = $this->_request->getControllerName();
        $this->view->view_name = $this->_request->getActionName();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error talks about serialization but I don't see the line.

Comment: That's because I'm not serializing the object, it's definitely got me stumped.

Comment: I see that the error is in the layout, not in the view...can you check this?

Comment: You're correct, the line that displays the avatar is in the layout.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Jhorra : Did you get this issue resolved

Comment: @shaile This question is from 2011.  I'm sure I did, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework's authorisation module uses sessions to preserve identity across page load and is probably serialising the User model under the covers (especially if you're just assigning the result of a Zend_Auth_Adapter call).

Try including the User class before the first call to getIdentity() and see if that fixes it (even if you're confident you're not serialising it yourself).

Comment: I've included the user file, but it still gives the error.  I've also edited the post with the full controller base class where these values are set.